# Why do I get a MissingPropertyException in the GroovyConsole?

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

When I execute the following script in the GroovyConsole it gives me a `MissingPropertyException` but I do not understand why:

```
def a = 'A'
def b() {
    println a
}
b()
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: 
    a for class: ConsoleScript18
at ConsoleScript18.b(ConsoleScript18:3)
at ConsoleScript18.run(ConsoleScript18:5)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a `Field` annotation to make it work:

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field
def a = 'A'
def b() {
    println a
}
b()
```

Answer (score 11):

The reason behind that is when you write any thing outside function without declaring any class in groovy it is moved to main function.

So the scope of variable `a` is limited to function `main()` which you are trying to access in another function `b()` of same class. But as there is no property `a` for class it throws `MissingPropertyException`.